# Can I use Callable threads without ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

Can I use Callable threads without ExecutorService? We can use instances of Runnable and subclasses of Thread without ExecutorService and this code works normally. But this code works consistently:

```
public class Application2 {

    public static class WordLengthCallable implements Callable {
        public static int count = 0;
        private final int numberOfThread = count++;

        public Integer call() throws InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
               sum += i;
            }
            System.out.println(numberOfThread);
            return numberOfThread;
       }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       WordLengthCallable wordLengthCallable1 = new WordLengthCallable();
       WordLengthCallable wordLengthCallable2 = new WordLengthCallable();
       WordLengthCallable wordLengthCallable3 = new WordLengthCallable();
       WordLengthCallable wordLengthCallable4 = new WordLengthCallable();
       wordLengthCallable1.call();
       wordLengthCallable2.call();
       wordLengthCallable3.call();
       wordLengthCallable4.call();
       try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

With ExecutorService the code works with few threads. Where are my mistakes?

Comment: Why are you calling the `call()` method directly? How does that create a background thread? This is like calling a Runnable object's `run()` method directly rather than putting it into a Thread and calling `start()` on the Thread. And why do you not want to use an ExecutorService?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: Class Thread hasn't constructor with Collable!!! I put question for the sake of my interest...

Comment: But for a direct answer to your direct question, as far as I understand things, no, you cannot use a Callable for creating background threads without using an ExecutorService.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels See Holger's answer, he has the solution using start() which is obviously what OP meant I think; does that not create a bg task ?

Answer (score 56):

While `interface`s are often created with an intended use case, they are never restricted to be used in that way.

Given a `Runnable` you can submit it to an `ExecutorService`, or pass it to the constructor of `Thread` or you can invoke its `run()` method directly like you can invoke any `interface` method without multi-threading involved. And there are more use cases, e.g. AWT `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)` so never expect the list to be complete.

Given a `Callable`, you have the same options, so it’s important to emphasize that, unlike your question suggests, invoking `call()` directly does not involve any multi-threading. It just executes the method like any other ordinary method invocation.

Since there is no constructor `Thread(Callable)` using a `Callable` with a `Thread` without an `ExecutorService` requires slightly more code:

```
FutureTask<ResultType> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(callable);
Thread t=new Thread(futureTask);
t.start();
// …
ResultType result = futureTask.get(); // will wait for the async completion
```

Answer (score 10):

The simple direct answer is that you need to use an ExecutorService if you want to use a Callable to create and run a background thread, and certainly if you want to obtain a Future object, or a collection of Futures. Without the Future, you would not be able to easily obtain the result returned from your Callable or easily catch Exceptions generated. Of course you could try to wrap your Callable in a Runnable, and then run that in a Thread, but that would beg the question of why, since by doing so you would lose much.

---

**Edit**
You ask in comment,

> Do you mean like the code below, which works?

```
public class Application2 {
    public static class WordLengthCallable implements Callable {
    public static int count = 0;
    private final int numberOfThread = count++;

    public Integer call() throws InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println(numberOfThread);
        return numberOfThread;
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
        new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
        new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
        new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new WordLengthCallable().call();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My reply: Yes. The code in the link "sort of" works. Yes, it creates background threads, but the results from the calculations performed in the Callables are being discarded, and all exceptions are being ignored. This is what I mean by "since by doing so you would lose much".

---

e.g.,

```
  ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
  List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
     futures.add(execService.submit(new WordLengthCallable()));
  }
  for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
     try {
        System.out.println("Future result: " + future.get());
     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println("done!");
  execService.shutdown();
```

---

**Edit 2**
Or if you want the results returned as they occur, use a CompletionService to wrap your ExecutorService, something I've never attempted before:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class CompletionServiceExample {
   public static class WordLengthCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
      private Random random = new Random();

      public Integer call() throws InterruptedException {
         int sleepTime = (2 + random.nextInt(16)) * 500;
         Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
         return sleepTime;
      }
   }

   private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 4;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
      CompletionService<Integer> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(
            execService);

      for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
         completionService.submit(new WordLengthCallable());
      }
      execService.shutdown();

      try {
         while (!execService.isTerminated()) {
            int result = completionService.take().get().intValue();
            System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
         }
      } catch (ExecutionException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      Thread.sleep(1000);
      System.out.println("done!");
   }
}
```

Comment: do you mean https://gist.github.com/AndrienkoAleksandr/b78b0e4e17b9c4facf90  this code works

Comment: @user3233853: I've updated my answer to include code that uses a CompletionService, something I've never used before, but which allows each task to complete and return without waiting for yet-to-compete tasks.

Comment: It's very interesting, we can use FutureTask with Callable: https://gist.github.com/AndrienkoAleksandr/747b5de2494f78e9be35

Comment: @user3233853: Using a FutureTask in this way is similar to using a Runnable wrapper. I'll have to check to see if it will trap excpetions adequately.

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Callable<String> c = () -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                return "true";
            };
            FutureTask<String> ft = new FutureTask<String>(c);
            Thread t = new Thread(ft);
            t.start();

            String result = ft.get();
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
/*
   Output: 
   Thread-0 
   true
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the `call()` method of a Callable or the `run()` method of a Runnable from your own thread directly. However this should be your last resort in special circumstances (for example integrating legacy code or unit tests). Scanners might detect this and alert you about a possible architectural problem, so it is better to not do it.

You could also use your own `ExecutorService` (or use Guava's `MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()`) which does basically the calling in the invoking thread. This will isolate your "unclean" usage of the interface to this Executor and allow it to use a different Executor whenever you want.

BTW: be careful, when you inherit from `Thread`, you should never use it without start/stop as that might lead to a leak. This is one of the reasons why bug scanners alert on calling run() methods directly.